# Under what conditions on the sequence {$a_n$}, $a_n>0$, the following set is compact in $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

a) parallelepiped {$x \in \ell^2, |x_n| \leq a_n$}

b) ellipsoid {$x\in \ell^2, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x_n|^2}{|a_n|^2} \leq 1$

I've already shown that a works if $|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$, but I really don't know what to do here because thats definitely not all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER. A necessary and sufficient condition for compactness, in both cases, is that $\,a_n\to 0$.

HINTS. First all all, if $x^k=(x^k_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $k\in\mathbb N$, using the fact that $|x_n^k|$, is bounded in $k$, for all $n$, and a diagonal argument one can pick a subsequence of $(x^k)$, cal it $(y^k)$, such that $y_n^k\to y_n$, for all $n$. Of course, this DOES NOT imply that $y^k\to y$ in the $\ell^2-$sense. It converges weakly.

In fact, if $y^k\to y$ weakly, and $|y^k|_{\ell^2}\to |y|_{\ell^2}$, then $y^k\to y$ strongly - In general, if $y^k\to y$ weakly, then $\limsup_{k\to\infty} |y^k|_{\ell^2}\le |y|_{\ell^2}$.

It remains to show that, $a_n\to 0$, if and only if $|y^k|_{\ell^2}\to |y|_{\ell^2}$.

Comment: Thank you! What exactly does $|y_k| \rightarrow |y|$ in the $l^2$-sense mean?

Comment: I fixed my answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your last statement? I'm so confused by this problem

Comment: Wait for part b, if $a_n$ goes to 0 wouldn't that make the sum blow up and not converge?